# How to implement MultiLabelBinarizer on this dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-multilearn

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    mid value   label
ID          
192 3   176.6   [9, 6, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 9, 2, 19...
192 4   73.6    [9, 6, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 9, 2, 19...
192 5   15.8    [9, 6, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 9, 2, 19...
194 3   9603.2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 1, 8, ...
```

I want to implement MultiLabelBinarizer after removing the duplicate values in each list of label column.

I have tried by looping the frame and removing duplicates. and also, the multilabel binarizer doesnt work and throws an exception

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    mlb.fit(y_train.data)
    X_train includes the mid and value columns
    y_train includes label values
    id is the index

I expect a prediction from the above values after the duplicate values are removed from each list of label column
```

Comment: This is the format of the dataframe.
192 3 176.6 [9, 6, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 9, 2, 19... 1                                                                
192 4 73.6 [9, 6, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 9, 2, 19...                                                                   
192 5 15.8 [9, 6, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 9, 2, 19...                                                                   194 3 9603.2 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 1, 8, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform pandas Data Frame to use for MultiLabelBinarizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494873/transform-pandas-data-frame-to-use-for-multilabelbinarizer)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your dataframe is named `df`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['ID','mid', 'value'])['label'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values)))
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(df2['label'])
mlb.transform(df2['label'])
```